# postinstall autorebase not running cleanly

Tags: cygwin

I am always getting an error when I add a package to cygwin, for example:
Package: Unknown package
    autorebase.bat exit code 1

/var/log/setup.log.full indicates the problem:

```
2013/12/02 10:07:57 running: cmd.exe /c "C:\cygwin64\etc\postinstall\autorebase.bat"
2013/12/02 10:07:57 abnormal exit: exit code=1
```

Running cmd.exe /c "C:\cygwin\etc\postinstall\autorebase.bat" complains about dash not being found.

```
C:\Users\xxx>cmd /c C:\cygwin64\etc\postinstall\autorebase.bat
'dash' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

So I changed autorebase.bat  from

```
@echo off
rem Postinstall scripts are always started from the Cygwin root dir
rem so we can just call dash from here
path .\bin;%path%
dash /bin/rebaseall -p
```

to

```
@echo off
rem Postinstall scripts are always started from the Cygwin root dir
rem so we can just call dash from here
C:
cd C:\cygwin64
path .\bin;%path%
dash /bin/rebaseall -pv
```

After this change I can run cmd /c C:\cygwin64\etc\postinstall\autorebase.bat cleanly from the command prompt but the error still shows up when I add a package using a installer.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3):

This problem keeps coming up and up... with complicated (but non-working) solutions on offer all over the message boards. A working solution is implied by https://cygwin.com/faq/faq.html#faq.using.bloda.  Oddly, I don't find any specific direction on the connection between the two from Cygwin.

As near as I understand it the Cygwin rebase (script 0p_000_autorebase.dash which executes at the end of a setup) runs into problems because it bumps up against other things you've installed. Most likely one of your anti-virus filters. One solution is to boot up in Safe+Networking mode, do the installation, then reboot. Everything worked fine (at least for me).

It probably doesn't help that the installation folders get a read-only flag (though I'm not exactly sure why this should matter, assuming that you're running setup in admin mode; but I might be missing something).

Answer (score 0):

If it doesn't work in any way, try to download the 32 bit version. If you try to add gcc, g++ it's the same for 32 or 64. If you try to add Cygwin/Mingw, the 32 bit compiler works fine for 64 bit machine (it's true for any application in any way)